# ansible-galaxy role fails with "do not have permission to modify /etc/ansible/roles/"

Tags: ansible, osx-yosemite, ansible-galaxy

`tl;dr` = **How do OS X users recommend working around this permissions error?**

I'm on OS X 10.10.1 and I recently installed Ansible running the following:

```
sudo pip install ansible --quiet
sudo pip install ansible --upgrade
```

I want to start off with a galaxy role to install homebrew and went to run this one with the following error:

```
$ ansible-galaxy install geerlingguy.homebrew
- downloading role 'homebrew', owned by geerlingguy
- downloading role from https://github.com/geerlingguy/ansible-role-homebrew/archive/1.0.1.tar.gz
- extracting geerlingguy.homebrew to /etc/ansible/roles/geerlingguy.homebrew
- error: you do not have permission to modify files in /etc/ansible/roles/geerlingguy.homebrew
- geerlingguy.homebrew was NOT installed successfully.
- you can use --ignore-errors to skip failed roles.
```

While I see `/etc` is owned by root, I don't see any notes in documentation saying I should `chmod` anything.

For reference:

```
$ ansible --version
ansible 1.8.2
  configured module search path = None
```

Is this expected or is my installation somehow wrong?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The default location for roles is `/etc/ansible/roles` (for version <= 2.3. Since v2.4, the default location has changed to `~/.ansible/roles/`, [an issue has been raised](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/34396)). You need to specify `--roles-path` when using `ansible-galaxy`. Here's what `ansible-galaxy install --help` says:

```
-p ROLES_PATH, --roles-path=ROLES_PATH
    The path to the directory containing your roles. The
    default is the roles_path configured in your
    ansible.cfg file (/etc/ansible/roles if not
    configured)
```

You can also set `roles_path` in `ansible.cfg`; [see the documentation for details](http://docs.ansible.com/intro_configuration.html#roles-path).

Comment: Thank you for an answer! I'm familiar with the default path and understand I can redirect it. My question could be stated more clearly as *how is this error normally remedied by those on OS X?* I imagine that defining `--roles-path` on every galaxy or playbook call would be annoying. There must be a smarter way. Any recommendations?

Comment: I have a custom `roles_path` in my `/etc/ansible/ansible.cfg` file, currently set to a location inside my home folder (e.g. `roles_path = ~/dev/ansible/roles`. (see the last line in the answer above). If you specify the `roles_path` globally, you never have to specify it on the command line.

Comment: Your second question is answered with `ansible.cfg`; follow the link to set the proper path.

Answer (score 4):

Or you can use `brew` to install `ansible`. To do it you would need to run:

```
brew install ansible
```

If you had any previous installations, it is possible that you will see a message like this:

> Error: The `brew link` step did not complete successfully The formula
>   built, but is not symlinked into /usr/local Could not symlink
>   bin/ansible Target /usr/local/bin/ansible already exists. You may want
>   to remove it:   rm '/usr/local/bin/ansible'
>
> To force the link and overwrite all conflicting files:   brew link
>   --overwrite ansible
>
> To list all files that would be deleted:   brew link --overwrite
>   --dry-run ansible
>
> Possible conflicting files are: /usr/local/bin/ansible
>   /usr/local/bin/ansible-console /usr/local/bin/ansible-doc
>   /usr/local/bin/ansible-galaxy /usr/local/bin/ansible-playbook
>   /usr/local/bin/ansible-pull /usr/local/bin/ansible-vault

So, run `brew link --overwrite ansible` to fix that. And now you will be able to install any roles without `sudo`.

Example:

> » ansible-galaxy install bennojoy.redis
>   - downloading role 'redis', owned by bennojoy
>   - downloading role from https://github.com/bennojoy/redis/archive/master.tar.gz
>   - extracting bennojoy.redis to /usr/local/etc/ansible/roles/bennojoy.redis
>   - bennojoy.redis was installed successfully

Answer (score 2):

As I saw you used "sudo" to install Ansible, I suppose it shall be OK to continue using "sudo" for ansible-galaxy installation. And that's what I just did.

Comment: You would need to have ansible available to root as well, which by default is not. In fact, your answer should be a comment altogether.